# NServiceBus service running on custom account

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

We are currently having some issues running a NServiceBus (3.3.7) service on an account that is not LocalSystem. It seems to have issues contacting RavenDB for saga access. We are currently getting an error like this:

```
2013-06-14 11:21:39,551 - WARN - NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport - Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=94ff04d1-e05a-414b-8a14-f243e7cc2e9e\387208
System.InvalidOperationException ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilder, TransportMessage msg)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg)
```

We have also changed the access rights to raven by setting Raven/AnonymousUserAccessMode to All, with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: is the custom account a local account or domain one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got this exception some time when the user account accessing the data did not have the necessary rights to access the server's data directories.

Try giving the account under which you're running your service access to `/Server/Database`.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what was needed. We set access to the user account on that raven folder and it worked.